# Macports ncurses error when trying to upgrade

Tags: macports

When I run the command `sudo port upgrade outdated` on my os x (lion) system, I get the following output.

```
--->  Computing dependencies for gettext
--->  Dependencies to be installed: ncurses
--->  Activating ncurses @5.9_1
Error: org.macports.activate for port ncurses returned: Image error: /opt/local/bin/captoinfo is being used by the active ncursesw port.  Please deactivate this port first, or use 'port -f activate ncurses' to force the activation.
Error: Failed to install ncurses
Please see the log file for port ncurses for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_ncurses/ncurses/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: ncurses
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

What should I do the be able to update? I have tried to force the activation but it did not work.

Comment: What details the log mentioned show

Comment: How is this question off topic? It's a "practical, answerable problem ... unique to the programming profession" about MacPorts, which is a "software tool commonly used by programmers." Or do you five not consider programmers who work on Mac OS X to be "real" programmers? :-)

Comment: I also do not understand why this question was closed.

Comment: So what was the justification for deciding this was 'off topic'? Thanks for posting this question and @HongPong for answering it correctly

Comment: This certainly is on-topic as this error comes up when using normal Ruby development tools such as rvm, I've voted to re-open it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just had something similar myself - not sure if it's related. See this ([source](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.macports.user/28039)):

> ncursesw was replaced by ncurses a long time ago. You must not have updated this MacPorts installation in
>   over a year; if you had upgraded sooner, this should have been handled more automatically for you but we've
>   already removed those upgrade paths since it was so long ago and we thought everybody would have upgraded
>   by now. You can just force ncursesw to uninstall since it's no longer needed:
>   sudo port -f uninstall ncursesw

also be sure to run

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

beforehand. That may have caused my issue - installing macports doesn't bring the latest package tree with it.

Comment: Installing MacPorts with the pre-compiled installer package does bring the latest ports tree with it. (You can use the Show Log function of the Installer to verify that it is running "port selfupdate" and thus downloading and indexing the ports tree.) Installing MacPorts by building from source is for users who want more control over their installation and therefore does not automatically sync or selfupdate for you.